# Angular - Control angular tab using dropdown option

Tags: javascript, angular, select, tabs, angular-components

Have created a tab component that allows the user to add multiple tabs and the individual tab information will get populated upon clicking the tab header which is working fine without any issue.

I would like to control/Manage the tab click using the dropdown select options.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tabs-example-peimcm)

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import { TabsComponent } from './tabs/tabs.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    {{ message }}
    <select
      id="select-menu-0"
      class="services-select"
      autoComplete="address-level1"
      (change)="handleDropdown($event)"
    >
    <option *ngFor="let item of options; index as i">
    {{item}}
  </option>
    </select>
    <my-tabs (onSelect)="handleTabClick($event)" [selectedIndex]="selectedTab">
      <my-tab [tabTitle]="'Tab 1'">
        Tab 1 content
      </my-tab>
      <my-tab tabTitle="Tab 2">
        Tab 2 content
      </my-tab>
      <my-tab tabTitle="Tab 3">
        Tab 3 content
      </my-tab>
    </my-tabs>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  message: string;
  selectedTab: number = 2;
  options: Array<string> = ['Tab 1', 'Tab 2', 'Tab 3'];

  handleTabClick(event) {
    console.log('$evnt', event);
    this.message = `${event.title} is clicked`;
  }

  handleDropdown(event) {
    console.log('EVENT', event.target.value, this.options.indexOf(event.target.value));
    this.selectedTab = this.options.indexOf(event.target.value);
    this.message = `${event.target.value} is clicked`;
    // this.handleTabClick(event);
  }
}
```

**tabs.component.ts**

```
import {
  Component,
  ContentChildren,
  QueryList,
  AfterContentInit,
  ViewChild,
  ComponentFactoryResolver,
  ViewContainerRef,
  Input,
  Output,
  EventEmitter
} from '@angular/core';

import { TabComponent } from './tab.component';
import { DynamicTabsDirective } from './dynamic-tabs.directive';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-tabs',
  template: `
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li *ngFor="let tab of tabs" (click)="sendMessage(tab)" [class.active]="tab.active">
        <a href="#">{{tab.title}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
    .tab-close {
      color: gray;
      text-align: right;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    `
  ]
})
export class TabsComponent implements AfterContentInit {

  @Input() selectedIndex: number;
  @Output() onSelect = new EventEmitter<string>();

  sendMessage(tab: Tab) {
    console.log('this.tabs', this.tabs.first, this.tabs.last);
    this.onSelect.emit(tab);
    this.tabs.toArray().forEach(tab => tab.active = false);
    tab.active = true;
  }
  
  @ContentChildren(TabComponent) tabs: QueryList<TabComponent>;
  
  // contentChildren are set
  ngAfterContentInit() {
    // get all active tabs
    console.log('selectedIndex', this.selectedIndex, typeof this.selectedIndex);
    console.log('ngAfter', this.tabs, this.tabs.toArray());
    let activeTabs = this.tabs.filter((tab)=>{ console.log('TBB', tab); return tab.active});
    console.log('activeTabs', activeTabs);

    if (this.selectedIndex) {
      console.log('SELECEELTLLT', this.tabs.toArray()[this.selectedIndex]);
      this.selectTab(this.tabs.toArray()[this.selectedIndex]);
    } else {
      this.selectTab(this.tabs.first);
    }
    
    // if there is no active tab set, activate the first
    // if(activeTabs.length === 0) {
    //   this.selectTab(this.tabs.first);
    // }
  }
  
  selectTab(tab: Tab){
    // deactivate all tabs
    console.log('tab', tab);
    this.tabs.toArray().forEach(tab => tab.active = false);
    
    // activate the tab the user has clicked on.
    tab.active = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you want to handle the `TAB` change process with `SELECT` element, I check your code you already have implement the `Parent Child Component Communication`. Now You have a select dropdown in your parent component & I believe you are facing problem to handle the change event of select dropdown within your child component,

As I notice you are passing `selectedIndex` to your child component, Now whenever change event of select dropdown occur, within that you are also modifying the value of `selectedIndex`, So try to implement the **OnChange interface** with your child component,

modify `tabs.component.ts` file:

[image]

Now provide the implementation of OnChange interface, by defining the method like below

[image]

Now if you try to change select dropdown value, it will also change the tab as well,

Comment: the problem has no relation with `OnChanges`

Comment: Alright! I suggest a way, you can achieve your expectation in this way as well, but may I know that, why you don't want to utilized this `OnChanges`?

Comment: You're correct, I thought that the problem has no relation with OnChanges, Is another aproach I`d not think, thanks for the advise -and for the lesson- (really if only has one Input is recomended use a setter, but is a good aproach too)

Comment: @SuneelKumar The solution works as expected.

Comment: @kabeerrifaye, Great!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest another aproach: control all by the "selectedIndex"

If you defined an `@Input` and a `@Output` like

```
  private _selectedIndex: number;
  @Input() set selectedIndex(value) {
    if (this.tabs && this.selectedIndex != value) {
      this._selectedIndex = value;                    //equal an auxiliar variable
      const tab=this.tabs.find((_x, i) => i == value);//find the "tab"
      if (tab){
          this.selectTab(tab);                            //call to selectTab
          this.onSelect.emit(tab);                        //emit onSelect
          this.selectedIndexChange.emit(value)            //emit selectedIndexChange
      }
    }
  }
  get selectedIndex(){
    return this._selectedIndex   //simple return the variable
  }

  @Output() selectedIndexChange = new EventEmitter<number>();
  @Output() onSelect = new EventEmitter<TabComponent>();
```

The code becomes more simpler.

```
  //In the tabs.component.html just change the selectedIndex
 <li
    *ngFor="let tab of tabs;let i=index"
    (click)="this.selectedIndex=i"
    [class.active]="tab.active"
  >

  //and in tabs.component.ts
  ngAfterContentInit() {
    if (this.selectedIndex) {
      this.selectTab(this.tabs.find((_x, i) => i == this.selectedIndex));
    } else {
      this.selectTab(this.tabs.first);
    }
  }

  selectTab(tab: Tab) {
    this.tabs.forEach(x => (x.active = x == tab));
  }
```

And you can use in your main.app (be carefull you need import FormsModule to use [(ngModel)])

```
<!--simple use [(ngModel)]-->
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedTab">
    <option *ngFor="let item of options; index as i" [value]="i">
      {{item}}
    </option>
</select>

<!--see the "bannana" notation in selectedIndex-->
<my-tabs (onSelect)="handleTabClick($event)" [(selectedIndex)]="selectedTab" >
     ....
</my-tabs>
```

Your [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tabs-example-ehjf8b?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

NOTE: See that you needn't convertToArray the QueryList, you can use the syntax `this.tabs.find((x,index)=>{...})`and use "index"

Comment: An alternative approach works and helps to reduces a couple of lines of code.